# Ruby on Rails, load a page in application even though user is not signed in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using devise. When a user 'Signs Up' they go to a page where they enter their name, email, password etc, and then click a 'Sign Up' button and, should all details entered be correct, they proceed into the application, which is what should happen.

What I want to do is add a link, 'By clicking "Create Account" you confirm that you accept the Terms and Conditions.' on the Sign Up page. That's all it is, a simple link - no check boxes or anything.

On the 'Sign Up' page code I have:

```
            <div class='t_and_c'>

    By clicking "Create Account" you confirm that you accept 
the <%= link_to "Terms and Conditions.", "static_pages#terms_and_conditions" %>
            </div>
```

But whenever a person clicks the link it keeps reloading the 'Sign Up' page - which is what it should do, because some code somewhere is telling the app not to load anything until the user has signed in so my question is:

How, just for this link, 'Terms and Conditions', can I load my terms_and_conditions.html.erb, even if the user is not sign in? I suppos it's some before_filter or skip_before filter but I don't know how to go about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your `StaticPagesController` to see if there is any `before_filter`, which may be some authentication method to prevent vistors' reading unless signed in.

If that is true, just add an exclude option on the "terms_and_conditions" method, like

```
before_filter :authorize, :except => :terms_and_conditions
```

Or

```
before_filter :authorize, :except => [:terms_and_conditions, :other_method_as_well]
```

#### Add

As per OP's update, there is before_filter but the filter is in the parent class `ApplicationController`.

In this case you can't simply add another before_filter in child class trying to overwrite it. Doing this will add one more filter in filter chain.

The solution is to use `skip_before_filter` like this

```
StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: :terms_and_conditions
```

*Method reference:* http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods/skip_before_filter

Comment: Yep.  I have an app where I do pretty much this exact thing.

Comment: Hi, there was no before_filter anywhere in my StaticPagesController so I added in the terms_and_conditions method: before_filter :authorize, :except => :terms_and_conditions. But it's still reloading the 'sign Up' page. At the top of my FrontEndController there's 'before_filter :authenticate_user!' and I changed this to 'before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => :terms_and_conditions', but still no joy. Any other ideas?

Comment: And why doesn't this work, the 'Unless'? Seems logical to me: By clicking "Create Account" you confirm that you accept the <%= link_to "Terms and Conditions.", "static_pages#terms_and_conditions" unless user_signed_in? %>

Comment: @ChristopheHarris, if no filter, don't add it. You can check if ApplicationController has such filter. For you second question, if you doing so there will be too much if/else/unless which is not nice.

Comment: In Application Controller I had 'before_filter :authenticate_user!' and I changed it to 'before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => :terms_and_conditions' but it still reloads the 'Sign Up' page. Any other tips? How would I specify t_and_c is in StaticPagesController, or do I need to? My method is definitely called terms_and_conditions.

Comment: Hi Billy, thanks for that. Works now. Marked your answer as accepted but am going to add mine to, just to give some more details about it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Sorted! My app ensures everybody has to sign in to get by. Unless it is a 'Terms and Conditions' link they click, on the 'Sign Up' page - which is how I want it to be.

First of all, I got my routes.rb sorted out. Nothing would have worked if I didn't do that.

Instead of:

```
    By clicking "Create Account" you confirm that you accept 
the <%= link_to "Terms and Conditions.", "static_pages#terms_and_conditions" %>
```

I put:

```
 By clicking "Create Account" you confirm that you accept 
the <%= link_to "Terms and Conditions.", t_and_c_path %>
```

and in my routes.rb:

```
 get "t_and_c", :to => "static_pages#terms_and_conditions"
```

In my ApplicationController at the very top I put:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => :terms_and_conditions
```

But it wouldn't work; the link 'Terms and Conditions' kept going again to the Sign Up page, telling me I had to sign up.

So the kind poster above said try in my StaticPagesController:

```
StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: :terms_and_conditions
```

So now, at least now I was getting an error message! - a syntax error. I don't know if it's a Ruby 1.8.7 thing (which I have) but I changed the code slightly to:

```
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => :terms_and_conditions
```

And now everything is working just fine.